# Javascript - Recursive function to iterate through elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, iteration

I've just started reading up on JavaScript and I'm trying to write a small recursive function that would search through given nodes and return a list of values as a string.

My HTML structure could be something like

```
<div id="parentfolder">parentfolder1
    <div class ="item1">item1</div>
    <div class ="item2">item2</div>
    <div id="parentfolder">parentfolder2
        <div class ="item1">item1</div>
        <div class ="item2">item2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And Here is my Javascript function:

```
function jsoncreator(parentfolderclass){
    var jstring = '';

    //get first occurance of parent folder
    var parentfolder = document.getElementById(parentfolderclass);
    var childnodes = parentfolder.childNodes;

    for (property in childnodes){
        jstring += property+ childnodes[property];
        if(childnodes[property] === parentfolderclass){
            jsoncreator(parentfolderclass);
            jstring += childnodes[property].value + '<br>';
        }
        else{
            //jstring += childnodes[i].value + '<br>';
        }
    }
    document.write(jstring);
}
```

All im getting back is

```
0[object Text]1[object HTMLDivElement]2[object Text]3[object HTMLDivElement]4[object Text]5[object HTMLDivElement]6[object Text]length7itemfunction item() { [native code] }
```

When I try to print the childnodes values, I get a bunch of undefined returns.

If anybody could explain what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: For a first, duplicated IDs are not valid HTML. Apart from that, you didn't actually describe what the returned array should contain exactly.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté it would return a list of values as a string

Comment: "Values" as in their text content?

Comment: `childnodes[property] === parentfolder` does not make sense as a node cannot be a descendant of itself; `var d = document.createElement('div'); d.appendChild(d); // Error: HierarchyRequestError: DOM Exception 3`

Comment: @PaulS. It was a typo. Its fixed now. Although, it doesnt make any changes..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to do something like the following (recursive cross-browser)

Javascript

```
function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walkTheDOM(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}

function textNodeValuesToArray(node) {
    if (typeof node === "string") {
        node = document.getElementById(node);
    }

    var arrayOfText = [];

    function pushText(currentNode) {
        if (currentNode.nodeType === 3) {
            arrayOfText.push(currentNode.nodeValue);
        }
    }

    walkTheDOM(node, pushText);

    return arrayOfText;
}

console.log(textNodeValuesToArray("parentfolder"));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/j28u6/)

Or using [`treewalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/treeWalker)

> **Browser compatibility**
>
> Supported by IE9+, FF2+, Chrome 1+, Safari 3+, Opera 9+

Javascript

```
function textNodeValuesToArray(node) {
    if (typeof node === "string") {
        node = document.getElementById(node);
    }

    var arrayOfText = [],
        treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(node, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, {
            acceptNode: function (node) {
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
            }
        }, false);

    while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
        arrayOfText.push(treeWalker.currentNode.nodeValue);
    }

    return arrayOfText;
}

console.log(textNodeValuesToArray("parentfolder"));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/a5zPQ/)

Without recursion and cross browser would be something like this

Javascript

> **Avoid using labels**
>
> Labels are not very commonly used in JavaScript since they make
>   programs harder to read and understand. As much as possible, avoid
>   using labels and, depending on the cases, prefer calling functions or
>   throwing an error.

```
function walkDOM(root, func) {
    var node = root;

    start: while (node) {
        func(node);
        if (node.firstChild) {
            node = node.firstChild;
            continue start;
        }

        while (node) {
            if (node === root) {
                break start;
            }

            if (node.nextSibling) {
                node = node.nextSibling;
                continue start;
            }

            node = node.parentNode;
        }
    }
}

function textNodeValuesToArray(node) {
    if (typeof node === "string") {
        node = document.getElementById(node);
    }

    var arrayOfText = [];

    function pushText(currentNode) {
        if (currentNode.nodeType === 3) {
            arrayOfText.push(currentNode.nodeValue);
        }
    }

    walkDOM(node, pushText);

    return arrayOfText;
}

console.log(textNodeValuesToArray("parentfolder"));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ufpwT/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="parentfolder">parentfolder1
  <div class ="item1">item1</div>
  <div class ="item2">item2</div>
  <div class="subfolder">parentfolder2
    <div class ="item1">item1</div>
    <div class ="item2">item2</div>
  </div>
</div>



var children = document.getElementById('parentfolder').getElementsByClassName('*');
var childValues = new Array();

for(i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
  if(children[i].className == 'subfolder') {
    continue;
  } else {
    childValues.push(children[i].innerHTML);
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably meant Tag instead of Class in `getElementsByTagName('*')`, and `childValues[] = ...` is not valid JS syntax.

Comment: childValues[] = ... is not valid JS syntax. Yeah - stuck in PHP mode. Fixed. And no - I meant getElementsByClassName('*')

Comment: Sure am. I've been using it for a couple of functions on my local machine. Nothing live to show, unfortunately.