# jQuery get all descendant nodes including text nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in jQuery to get all descendant nodes of a parent node, including text nodes, recursively? I know the `$.contents()` method, but as the jQuery documentation states:

> the `.contents()` method allows us to search through the immediate children of these elements in the DOM tree

My problem is, that I have a child node that contains more (non-text) nodes, and I need instead of just the parent.
I am trying some workaround now:

```js
var contents = container.contents();
var foo = $('.foo');
var index = contents.index(foo);
contents.splice(index,1,$('.foo').contents());
```

...but this inserts the *array* instead of the individual elements. My final step would be pushing the elements to the `contents` array one by bone, but I'd like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004547/javascript-recursive-function-to-iterate-through-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do but in order to get *all descendant nodes* of a certain element you may use the following:

```
var nodes = $('*', container).addBack().contents();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5vfBg/

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use jQuery 1.7, so I don't have the `addBack()` function. Besides, this is what I would like to achieve (based on the jsfiddle)

Comment: @Sleeper9 Then you should use good old `andSelf()` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/5vfBg/1/.

Comment: Yes, got it working now, exactly what I wanted. Thanks!